# Order by character occurrences in rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this piece of code

```
.order('LENGTH(full_address) ASC')
```

Instead of ordering by length of the column I want to order by occurrences of '/', anyway to do this in rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do SQL trick - substract length of address after replacing slash with empty string from original address length and then order by it:

```
.order("(LENGTH(full_address) - LENGTH(REPLACE(full_address, '/', ''))) ASC")
```

Comment: Thank you! With a slight modification (you forgot a paranthesis at the end) and swapped to quotation marks so I didn't have to escape the single quotation mark.